# How to simulate key press event?

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

How to simulate key press event with ksh|bash script?

Comment: Why do you want this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is complicated. But what I need is for OS to consider output of this script like real key events.

Comment: Do you want the keypress in the GUI (which?) or in the terminal?

Comment: In GUI. To be more specific in VNC session.

Answer (score 1):

Try xdotool: http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not suitable for my OS (SCO Unix).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why xdotool wasn't compatible with SCO ; but maybe these are. What about [Expect](http://www.nist.gov/mel/msid/expect.cfm), or [replayXt](http://jan.newmarch.name/SW.html#replayXt)?

**See Also**
[DejaGnu](http://www.gnu.org/software/dejagnu/), a testing framework based on Expect
[replayXt](http://jan.newmarch.name/SW.html#replayXt), control of Athena and Motif based GUIs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automate things in KDE, I would suggest you to look at DCOP [1]. You can interface full-fledged KDE applications using DCOP calls from Bash/Ksh script.

Take a look at this tutorial from IBM [2] as well. You can do many interesting things using DCOP.

- [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCOP
- [2] http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-dcop/